# How to create the multi-level url in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create the multilevel URL in Codeigniter and I defined the following route in route.php file

```
$route['users/(:any)/usersnippet/(:any)'] = 'users/usersnippet/$1';
```

By this, I want to create the following URL

```
https://websiteurl.com/users/john-kendey-115643/usersnippets/Tru564Y
```

How do I create this?

Comment: So you're trying to call the users class and the usersnippet method inside the users controller. I think you're just missing .../$1/$2 to pass both parameters.

    $route['users/(:any)/usersnippet/(:any)'] = 'users/usersnippet/$1/$2';

Comment: @DinoCajic still getting not found page

Comment: @mickmackusa I think the question is quite different as the one you marked as a dupe, it asks for a routes solution, not how to address an url

Comment: @Vickel  there are answers on that page that speak on routing as well.  You are welcome to vote to reopen, or you can find a better duplicate.  I stopped looking after I found one, but I am very sure that there will be multiple duplicates for this basic CI task.  I can appreciate that you are hunting for an unanswered question.  There will be more to earn a hat on.

Comment: @mickmackusa I cannot vote to reopen, as I'm involved in the question? Also its not so basic, as the users tries to get parameters to 2 different controllers with one url. Which is wrong approach, I've not seen it before TBH

Comment: You can **definitely** vote to reopen. You just cannot campaign for the page to be reopened.  I don't read it to say that the parameters are meant for two different controllers.  This is not explicitly expressed.  I suppose this means that the question is also Unclear and should not be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

> By this, I want to create the following URL

You don’t create an URL with [CI routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html), you route your URL to a controller function and make parameters available to that function.

Your example URL

```
https://websiteurl.com/users/john-kendey-115643/usersnippets/Tru564Y
```

is actually a wrong concept, as everything following “`/user/john-kendey-115643/`” is considered a parameter. See [CI URLs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

I would resolve your problem with a much cleaner and user-friendly URL:

URL:

```
https://websiteurl.com/users/john-kendey-115643/Tru564Y
```

Route:

```
$route['users/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'users/process_users/$1/$2';
```

Controller

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
        // load your models
        $this->load->model('Get_user');
        $this->load->model('Get_user_snippet');
    }   
    
    function process_users ($user, $snippet){
        // get userdata
        $data['user']=$this->Get_user->get_the_userdata ($user);
        $data['snippet']=$this->Get_user_snippet->get_the_snippetdata ($snippet);
        // do something with $data
    }

}
```

Models (Get_user, Get_user_snippet):

```
// Query the database for the data you need
```